# How can this code be better structured in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir as my first functional-style language. As a first simple project to familiarize myself with the environment and syntax, I chose to build a simple program that computes the prime factors for a number provided on the command line. This is my first solution:

```
defmodule Prime do
  defp is_factor?(number, divisor) do
    cond do
      rem(number, divisor) == 0 -> divisor
      true                      -> nil
    end
  end

  defp not_nil?(thing) do
    !is_nil(thing)
  end

  def factors(number) when number == 1 do
    []
  end

  def factors(number) do
    1..div(number, 2)
      |> Enum.map(&(is_factor?(number, &1)))
      |> Enum.filter(&not_nil?/1)
  end

  def is_prime?(number) when number == 1 do
    true
  end

  def is_prime?(number) do
    factors(number) == [1]
  end

  def prime_factors(number) do
    factors(number)
      |> Enum.filter(&is_prime?/1)
  end
end

input = hd(System.argv)
number = String.strip(input) |> String.to_integer
IO.puts "Prime factors of #{number} are #{inspect Prime.prime_factors(number)}"
```

It works, but runs rather slowly. On my laptop, run times are around 11 seconds to compute the prime factors of 50,000,000.

As I read more, it seems like this original solution is not very Elixir-like. So I restructured the code to this:

```
defmodule PrimeFactors do
  def of(n) do
    _factors(n, div(n, 2))
  end

  defp _factors(_n, 1) do
    [1]
  end
  defp _factors(n, divisor) when rem(n, divisor) == 0 do
    cond do
      is_prime?(divisor) -> _factors(n, divisor - 1) ++ [divisor]
      true               -> _factors(n, divisor - 1)
    end
  end
  defp _factors(n, divisor) do
    _factors(n, divisor - 1)
  end

  defp is_prime?(1) do
    true
  end
  defp is_prime?(n) do
    of(n) == [1]
  end
end

input = hd(System.argv)
number = String.strip(input) |> String.to_integer
IO.puts "Prime factors of #{number} are #{inspect PrimeFactors.of(number)}"
```

Typical run time of this code to compute the prime factors of 50,000,000 is substantially worse: over 17 seconds.

I built equivalent programs in Swift and Ruby. Optimized Swift runs in just over 0.5 seconds, and Ruby (2.2, and never known for its speed) runs in a bit over 6 seconds.

My primary question is: How should the Elixir code be structured to be more idiomatic and to avoid the performance problems I'm seeing?

I'm also left with some concerns that given such a simple problem, it's possible to write Elixir code that varies wildly in efficiency. Perhaps this is mostly my inexperience in functional styles showing?

Comment: One thing you can do for sure is avoid the `++` operator when you want to add an element to a list. Elixir lists are made of [cons cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons), so adding an element to the end of a list should be a O(n) operation while adding it to the head of the list is O(1). A common pattern is to prepend elements to a list (`[new_el|list]`) and use `Enum.reverse/1` to reverse the list before using it.

Comment: That's good to know, but in this case it doesn't make much of a difference. I'm guessing that's because the list of prime factors tends to be quite short (for 50,000,000 the list is [1, 2, 5]).

Comment: Also, I think you can start checking for prime factors at `sqrt(n)` instead of `n / 2`. That's IIRC, I've not dealt with prime numbers since algos :)

Comment: OK, another good suggestion, but the algorithm is the same in the other implementations. I feel like I'm missing a basic understanding of how to structure Elixir code to avoid performance problems. It doesn't seem like there should be such a wide gap between the Ruby implementation and a good Elixir implementation.

Comment: Can you point us to the Ruby code?

Comment: Sure. It's at https://gist.github.com/sjmadsen/9d5b23aad5e49dc865c5.

Comment: I just tried this on Windows 8 with Elixir 1.0.2.  21 seconds. Can you spell out a few more details: 1.) How are you timing this?  2.) Which version of Elixir and 3.) Which OS?  (I timed the code with the Erlang timer module per this tip from Jose Valim: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-core/lhxQyTLzN0Y/SiE5HsarCCoJ

Comment: That code is certainly slow for large numbers, but I believe the main reason for it is the algorithmic complexity. Here's my quick&sloppy take on the solution which is most probably far from optimal but works much faster than the original code: https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/98e6465bf854a9d86cba

Comment: Could be the fact that you're using lazy evaluation too @sasajuric.  Definitely much faster for sure.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Actually, I'm not using lazy evaluation here, but I'm doing less divisions than OP. This approach can surely be improved in various ways (perhaps by using a sieve?), but it still got me a couple of order of magnitudes further than the original code.

Comment: Ack--I see what I missed.  Never mind.

Comment: Elixir 1.0.2, "user" time value from Unix `time(1)`. I agree that the algorithm is sub-optimal. I'm less concerned about that than if I am structuring the solution in a way that results in slow Elixir code. Put another way: how fast can I expect well-written Elixir code to run compared to other languages when implementing the same algorithm?

Comment: Raw speed is not the primary focus of Erlang, so if it's heavily CPU bound, I'd expect Elixir/Erlang to be slower than most mainstream languages. In this example, I suspect Ruby wins since you do a lot of iterations with C implemented Ruby functions (map, reject, compact), while Elixir iterations are standard Erlang bytecode. Also, (not relevant in this example), using `time` measures Erlang VM startup time which may affect the result. I really don't think this is a good example though, because once you optimize the code algorithmically, the difference may become insignificant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me start with a quick rant then we will move to the answer. I believe we are worrying about the wrong thing here. Once you posted the Ruby code, my first thought was: why does the Elixir code does not look as clean as the Ruby one?

Let's solve this problem first:

```
defmodule PrimeFactors do
  def of(n) do
    factors(n, div(n, 2)) |> Enum.filter(&is_prime?/1)
  end

  def factors(1, _), do: [1]
  def factors(_, 1), do: [1]
  def factors(n, i) do
    if rem(n, i) == 0 do
      [i|factors(n, i-1)]
    else
      factors(n, i-1)
    end
  end

  def is_prime?(n) do
    factors(n, div(n, 2)) == [1]
  end
end

IO.inspect PrimeFactors.of(50_000_000)
```

Much better. Let's run this cleaner version? 3.5 seconds on my machine (compared to 24 seconds of the earlier one).

Now with a cleaner code, it is easier to compare what is wrong in your implementation. Your `_factors` function is actually `_factors_and_prime` because you are already checking if the number is prime in there. So when you check for `is_prime?`, you are actually computing "factors and prime" which is much more expensive to calculate than the actual "factors" since it ends up calling `is_prime?` again and recursively.

As someone, somewhere, said:

1. Make it work
2. Make it beautiful
3. Make it fast (if necessary)

:)

Comment: Changing the `factors(n, i)` function from using the `if`control structure to using function definitions with guards: 
`def factors(n, i) when rem(n, i) == 0, do: [i|factors(n, i-1)]` and 
`def factors(n, i), do: factors(n, i-1)` 
makes this run even (~5%) faster. This seems also more idiomatic.
José, had you in this case any reason for using the `if` control structure in favor of functions with guards? Interesting would be also to know in detail why does the second run faster.

Comment: That would be even better indeed. :) Although I don't expect it to be practically faster. The underlying code they compile to is very similar.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, José. The Ruby code is much cleaner because I'm more familiar with it. I'll get there with Elixir eventually. Thanks for pointing out that the two algorithms weren't the same, and that was the root of my Elixir performance issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct solution; if you compute prime factors for `PrimeFactors.of(27)` it returns `[3, 1]`. Number 1 is not a prime number so should be excluded from the results. The bigger problem is that multiplying all of the factors should give you the original number, thus the correct result should be `[3, 3, 3]`. You could probably modify the `factors` definitions to div the number and keep the divisor the same.

Answer (score 8):

Optimized works in under a second:

```rb
defmodule PF do

  @doc "Calculates the unique prime factors of a number"
  def of(num) do
    prime_factors(num)
    |> Enum.uniq
  end

  @doc """
  Calculates all prime factors of a number by finding a low factor
  and then recursively calculating the factors of the high factor.
  Skips all evens except 2.
  Could be further optimized by only using known primes to find factors.
  """
  def prime_factors(num , next \\ 2)
  def prime_factors(num, 2) do
    cond do
      rem(num, 2) == 0 -> [2 | prime_factors(div(num, 2))]
      4 > num          -> [num]
      true             -> prime_factors(num, 3)
    end
  end
  def prime_factors(num, next) do
    cond do
      rem(num, next) == 0 -> [next | prime_factors(div(num, next))]
      next + next > num   -> [num]
      true                -> prime_factors(num, next + 2)
    end
  end

end
```

Bonus, tests:

```rb
ExUnit.start

defmodule PFTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "prime factors are correct" do
    numbers = [4, 15, 22, 100, 1000, 2398, 293487,
               32409850, 95810934857, 50_000_000]
    Enum.map(numbers, fn (num) ->
      assert num == Enum.reduce(PF.prime_factors(num), &*/2)
    end)
  end
end
```

We end up writing much more literate/idiomatic elixir by reducing the problem domain. Further optimization could be achieved but perhaps at a loss of readability without significant performance gain. Also, as docs and tests are built into the platform, including them is painless and makes the code much more readable. :)

Comment: Bonus points for taking advantage of Elixir's sweet unit testing and built in documentation features.